# How to integrate emberjs mocha-phantomjs tests with dom event listeners

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dom-events, ember-testing, mocha-phantomjs

In our mocha-phantomjs unit tests for our ember application, I'm adding some event listeners to a `video` element in the DOM:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  this._super();
  var video = this.$('.video-review').get(0);
  var self = this;
  video.addEventListener('error', function(err){
    self.set('isReviewEnabled', false);
    console.error(video.error);
  }, false);
},
```

Now I need to test the `video` element throwing an error and assert the graceful degradation code executes properly:

```
test("add video", function(done) {
  Ember.run(function() {
    widget.setFile({type: 'video/mp4', size: 100000});
    // should cause video element to throw error
  });
  // app gracefully degrades and is able to upload without .video-review
  findWithAssert('.alert-upload-ready')
```

All of my ember code executes as expected, except for the DOM video element event listener which never fires. The graceful degradation depends on this event listener firing. So I guess my question boils down to this: ?

**How do I force/simulate DOM element events in an ember mocha-phantomjs test?**